# Python itertools get permutations and combinations of a list of lists

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

My brain is going to explode as I try to figure how to get all permutations and combinations of a list of lists in Python. The problem is to write a function which would for the following input list `[['I1', 'I2', 'I3'], ['I2', 'I3']]` return the following:

```
[['I1', 'I2', 'I3'], ['I2', 'I3']]
[['I1', 'I3', 'I2'], ['I2', 'I3']]
[['I2', 'I1', 'I3'], ['I2', 'I3']]
[['I2', 'I3', 'I1'], ['I2', 'I3']]
[['I3', 'I1', 'I2'], ['I2', 'I3']]
[['I3', 'I2', 'I1'], ['I2', 'I3']]
[['I1', 'I2', 'I3'], ['I3', 'I2']]
[['I1', 'I3', 'I2'], ['I3', 'I2']]
[['I2', 'I1', 'I3'], ['I3', 'I2']]
[['I2', 'I3', 'I1'], ['I3', 'I2']]
[['I3', 'I1', 'I2'], ['I3', 'I2']]
[['I3', 'I2', 'I1'], ['I3', 'I2']]
[['I2', 'I3'], ['I1', 'I2', 'I3']]
[['I2', 'I3'], ['I1', 'I3', 'I2']]
[['I2', 'I3'], ['I2', 'I1', 'I3']]
[['I2', 'I3'], ['I2', 'I3', 'I1']]
[['I2', 'I3'], ['I3', 'I1', 'I2']]
[['I2', 'I3'], ['I3', 'I2', 'I1']]
[['I3', 'I2'], ['I1', 'I2', 'I3']]
[['I3', 'I2'], ['I1', 'I3', 'I2']]
[['I3', 'I2'], ['I2', 'I1', 'I3']]
[['I3', 'I2'], ['I2', 'I3', 'I1']]
[['I3', 'I2'], ['I3', 'I1', 'I2']]
[['I3', 'I2'], ['I3', 'I2', 'I1']]
```

Any ideas how to make it efficiently in Python? Thanks!

**P.S.** The function should return all permutations and combinations for input list of lists of any size, not just the two-element list shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a full functional approach you can use `permutations()` and `product()` and `chain()` functions from `itertools` module and built in function `map()`:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, product, chain
>>> def my_prod(lst):
...     return product(*map(permutations, lst))
... 
>>> 
>>> list(chain(*map(my_prod, permutations(lst))))
[(('I1', 'I2', 'I3'), ('I2', 'I3')), (('I1', 'I2', 'I3'), ('I3', 'I2')), (('I1', 'I3', 'I2'), ('I2', 'I3')), (('I1', 'I3', 'I2'), ('I3', 'I2')), (('I2', 'I1', 'I3'), ('I2', 'I3')), (('I2', 'I1', 'I3'), ('I3', 'I2')), (('I2', 'I3', 'I1'), ('I2', 'I3')), (('I2', 'I3', 'I1'), ('I3', 'I2')), (('I3', 'I1', 'I2'), ('I2', 'I3')), (('I3', 'I1', 'I2'), ('I3', 'I2')), (('I3', 'I2', 'I1'), ('I2', 'I3')), (('I3', 'I2', 'I1'), ('I3', 'I2')), (('I2', 'I3'), ('I1', 'I2', 'I3')), (('I2', 'I3'), ('I1', 'I3', 'I2')), (('I2', 'I3'), ('I2', 'I1', 'I3')), (('I2', 'I3'), ('I2', 'I3', 'I1')), (('I2', 'I3'), ('I3', 'I1', 'I2')), (('I2', 'I3'), ('I3', 'I2', 'I1')), (('I3', 'I2'), ('I1', 'I2', 'I3')), (('I3', 'I2'), ('I1', 'I3', 'I2')), (('I3', 'I2'), ('I2', 'I1', 'I3')), (('I3', 'I2'), ('I2', 'I3', 'I1')), (('I3', 'I2'), ('I3', 'I1', 'I2')), (('I3', 'I2'), ('I3', 'I2', 'I1'))]
```

Here the `map` function maps the `permutations` on your sub lists and then `product` will create the products of permutations.

As another way (and slightly faster) you can use a list comprehension instead of `map()`:

```
>>> def my_prod(lst):
...     return product(*[permutations(sub) for sub in  lst])
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not clear, but while your answer works for the input list given in the question, it will not return all permutations and combinations for a longer list of lists, for example `[['I1', 'I2', 'I3'], ['I2', 'I3'], ['I5', 'I6']]`